# How set DPI resolution of a TIFF image with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, resolution, tiff, dpi

I use this code to draw a image and save it as TIFF with Delphi 2006:

```
var Bmp: TBitmap;
  MF: TMetaFile;
  MetafileCanvas: TMetafileCanvas;
begin
  Gdip := TGDIPlusFull.Create('gdiplus.dll');
  MF := TMetaFile.Create;

  MF.Width := 1000;
  MF.Height := 1100;

  MetafileCanvas := TMetafileCanvas.Create(MF, 0);
  MetafileCanvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  MetafileCanvas.Brush.Style := bsDiagCross;
  MetafileCanvas.Ellipse(50, 50, 300 - 50, 200 - 50);
  MetafileCanvas.Free;

  Bmp := Gdip.DrawAntiAliased(MF);

  Image1.Picture.Assign(Bmp);
  SynGDIPlus.SaveAs(Bmp, 'c:\test.tif', gptTIF); 
  Bmp.Free;

  MF.Free;
  FreeAndNil(GdiP);
end;
```

NOTE I use free framework fromhttp://www.synopse.info.

The code works very well. However I have a problem. How can I set the TIFF resolution.
My test.tif image have 96 DPI (screen resoltion), but I need of 200 DPI.
Note I cannot want change the image dimensions (width and heght), becuase there are right, I want change only DPI resolution.

I have found many answer about this question but nothing about Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

I've added the following method:

```
procedure TSynPicture.BitmapSetResolution(DPI: single);
begin
  if (fImage<>0) and fAssignedFromBitmap and (DPI<>0) then
    Gdip.BitmapSetResolution(fImage,DPI,DPI);
end;
```

Which will call the corresponding GDI+ API for setting a bitmap resolution.

Then it should be specified when saving:

```
procedure SaveAs(Graphic: TPersistent; const FileName: TFileName;
  Format: TGDIPPictureType; CompressionQuality: integer=80;
  MaxPixelsForBiggestSide: cardinal=0; BitmapSetResolution: single=0); overload;
var Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);
  try
    SaveAs(Graphic,Stream,Format,CompressionQuality,MaxPixelsForBiggestSide,
      BitmapSetResolution);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

So you could be able to write in your code:

```
  Bmp := Gdip.DrawAntiAliased(MF);
  Image1.Picture.Assign(Bmp);
  SynGDIPlus.SaveAs(Bmp, 'c:\test.tif', gptTIF, 80, 0, 200); // force 200 DPI
  Bmp.Free;
```

See [this commit](http://synopse.info/fossil/info/5850eaeb4b).

Answer (score 1):

TWICImage class is able to save DPI information for TIF files, but the access to this feature is not apparent at first glance. Just call the SetResolution function of the Handle.

```
tif := TWICImage.Create;
...
tif.Handle.SetResolution( DPI_X, DPI_Y);
```